# How to log in IHostingStartup.Configure()

Tags: logging, asp.net-core-2.2

I have implemented a [HostingStartup assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in asp.net-core-2.2. I am interested in being able to log messages in [Configure()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingstartup.configure?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method. However, the [IHostingStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingstartup?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class is not instantiated using DI (because the webhost has not yet been built) so I cannot inject an ILogger or ILoggerFactory into the class.

Currently I am using System.Diagnostics.Trace to trace the configuration code and [enabling stdout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-azure-app-service) but I don't want to leave this on in production but would still like the ability to log the HostingStartup code and potential issues.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
public class HostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
   public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.Configure(app =>
       {
           var loggerFactory = app.ApplicationServices
               .GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
           var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HostingStartup>();

           logger.LogInformation("Logged in HostingStartup");
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // register any locals
        }
   }
```

Comment: IWebHostBuilder does not have a Configure method.

Comment: @Cariarer is correct here, IWebHostBuilder does not have a configure method. I am still unable to find a way to access the logger in the IHostingStartup.Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) override.

Comment: Leon was probably relying on the `IWebHostBuilder.Configure` extension method found in [WebHostBuilderExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderextensions.configure).  Personally, I found it somewhat impractical to use that extension method, since it seems to replace the existing method rather than adding to it.